# table counterpart of column_ifexists()

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

We do have a function `column_ifexists()` which refers to a certain column if it exists, otherwise it refers to another option if we provide. Is there a similar function for table? I want to refer to a table and run some logic against it in the query , if the table exists , but if it doesn't exist, there shouldn't be a failure -- it should simply return no data.

e.g.

```
table_ifexists('sometable') | ...<logic>...
```

Comment: Similar to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55575717/check-if-a-table-exists-in-kusto-language

Comment: Answered, however this may indicate a problematic data engineering flow.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the fields referenced in the query should be defined in the dummy table, otherwise in case of non-existing table, the query will yield an exception

> Failed to resolve scalar expression named '...'

In the following example these fields are `StartTime`, `EndTime` & `EventType`

##### Table exists

```
let requested_table = "StormEvents";
let dummy_table = datatable (StartTime:datetime, EndTime:datetime, EventType:string)[];
union isfuzzy=true table(requested_table), dummy_table
| where EndTime - StartTime > 30d
| summarize count() by EventType
```

| EventType | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| Drought | 1635 |
| Flood | 20 |
| Heat | 14 |
| Wildfire | 4 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA12OzQqCQBSF94LvcHGlYBC0M2znE+guIsbmVgPOaHfuFCM9fGORhbvD4Ts/HTIQ3hxaRnlk0XYIJSQ196SrOxq2yTaOukBJp7WfCSlYfHRasyBulMYimMhB5FAZuXSmssYPWFgmZS7Z/hCKnVG9AWXPbhx9yeQQ3q3p4lOW/+/H0RMeVyT87sAK5hewg81aTogNCUFqRDj1znCaQet/P149H+L4+gAAAA==)

##### Table does not exist

```
let requested_table = "StormEventsXXX";
let dummy_table = datatable (StartTime:datetime, EndTime:datetime, EventType:string)[];
union isfuzzy=true table(requested_table), dummy_table
| where EndTime - StartTime > 30d
| summarize count() by EventType
```

| EventType | count_ |
| --- | --- |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA12OzQqCQBSF94LvcHGlYBC0M2zXE+hCiIixudWAM9adO8VID99YZOHucPjOT4cMhDeHllEeWLQdQglJxT3p7R0N26ZpknUcdQGUTms/QVKw+Oi0YkFcK41FMJGDyGFr5NwZ+2p/xcIyKXPOdvtQ7IzqDSh7csPgSyaH8G5NZ7ey/H8/jp7wuCDhdwcWML2ADayWckRsSAhSA8Kxd4bTDFr/+/EC+g5HKf0AAAA=)

Comment: See updated answer